# Overloading methods, reusing code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance, refactoring

How can I refactor this so that I dont repeat the same code in each method?

```
    private void setupTooltip(Grid obj)
    {
        var controls = obj.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>();
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            control.ToolTip = "Code is <" + control.Name + ">";
        }
    }

    private void setupTooltip(StackPanel obj)
    {
        var controls = obj.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>();
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            control.ToolTip = "Code is <" + control.Name + ">";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Grid` and what is `StackPanel`? Do they share a common base class or interface?

Comment: This is the second refactoring question I have read today... Stack Overflow is not the place for this, check out [the Code Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: OK, will read there first in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one method that takes in a `Panel` object.  Both StackPanel and Grid inherit from there, and you don't look to be using any control specific methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) is defined in [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) class.

```
private void setupTooltip(Panel obj)
{
    var controls = obj.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>();
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        control.ToolTip = "Code is <" + control.Name + ">";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the common base class [**`Panel`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) as the method's parameter you can use the following method for both `Grid` and `StackPanel`:

```
private void setupTooltip(Panel panel)
{
    var controls = panel.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>();
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        control.ToolTip = "Code is <" + control.Name + ">";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, seems like its job done!

Answer (score 0):

If `StackPanel` and `Grid` share a common base class or interface, you can change the parameter for your method to that type and remove the second method.